# Adding values to a list up to a certain index in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, tuples

I am having trouble with iteration, especially in terms of stopping iteration when I reach a certain a value. When I reach this value, I want to perform a certain task (explained below) and move on to the next element in the list.

Here's what I'd like to accomplish. I have a list `lst` that looks like this:

```
[(1, 'x', 'NA'),
 (2, 'x', 'low'),
 (3, 'x', 'NA'),
 (4, 'x', 'NA'),
 (5, 'x', 'NA'),
 (6, 'x', 'high'),
 (7, 'x', 'NA'),
 (8, 'x', 'NA'),
 (9, 'x', 'NA'),
 (10, 'x', 'NA'),
 (11, 'x', 'low'),
 (12, 'x', 'NA'),
 (13, 'x', 'NA'),
 (14, 'x', 'NA'),
 (15, 'x', 'high'),
 (16, 'x', 'NA'),
 (17, 'x', 'NA'),
 (18, 'x', 'NA'),
 (19, 'x', 'NA'),
 (20, 'x', 'NA'),
 (21, 'x', 'low'),
 (22, 'x', 'NA'),
 (23, 'x', 'NA'),
 (24, 'x', 'NA'),
 (25, 'x', 'high'),
 (26, 'x', 'NA')]
```

What I'd like to do is keep track of each `low_lst` and each `high_lst`.

For instance, elements would be added to a `low_lst` if the second index 
in the tuple is marked as `low` and all other elements not marked as `high` following that element would be added to the list as well. In the first case, it would be `[2,3,4,5]`.

`6` would not be included because it is marked as `high.` So, all elements including `6` and following that would be added to a `high_lst`: `[6,7,8,9,10]`.

The final output should look like:

```
low_lst = [[2,3,4,5],[11,12,13,14], [21,22,23,24]]
high_lst = [[6,7,8,9,10],[15,16,17,18,19,20], [25,26]]
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
vals_list_low = []
vals_list_high = []

i = -1
for x, y, z in lst:
    if z == "low":
        vals_list_min.append(lst[:i])
    if z == "high":
        vals_list_max.append(lst[:i])
        i += 1
```

I am trying to add all elements up to a certain index, but am unsure how.

Comment: Wouldnt the first low be 1,2,3,4?  the next two start at 11, then 21.

There's a similar issue with the high list, I'd expect the first to be 5 to 10.

Using a modulus, or two, an algorithm can be made, but the initial entries seem odd because 1 was skipped.  Is 1 supposed to be skipped?

Comment: @FruckubusCrunt technically, yes, but I am considering the starting value of 'low' to be the row in which it is actually marked as 'low', so yes, it's supposed to be skipped.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry, I understand what's going on now.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to keep track of the state of your list generation.  When you hit a `'low'` element, it switches to the `low_lst`; and vice-versa for `'high'`.  A dictionary maps the state to the list, and a sublist holds the values.

```
low_lst = []
high_lst = []

STATE = None
state_dict = {'low': low_lst, 'high': high_lst}

for x, y, z in lst:
    if z=='low' or z=='high':
        STATE = z
        sublist = []
        state_dict[STATE].append(sublist)
        sublist.append(x)
    if STATE and z=='NA':
        sublist.append(x)

low_lst
high_list
# returns:
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24]]
[[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [25, 26]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [(1, 'x', 'NA'),
 (2, 'x', 'low'),
 (3, 'x', 'NA'),
 (4, 'x', 'NA'),
 (5, 'x', 'NA'),
 (6, 'x', 'high'),
 (7, 'x', 'NA'),
 (8, 'x', 'NA'),
 (9, 'x', 'NA'),
 (10, 'x', 'NA'),
 (11, 'x', 'low'),
 (12, 'x', 'NA'),
 (13, 'x', 'NA'),
 (14, 'x', 'NA'),
 (15, 'x', 'high'),
 (16, 'x', 'NA'),
 (17, 'x', 'NA'),
 (18, 'x', 'NA'),
 (19, 'x', 'NA'),
 (20, 'x', 'NA'),
 (21, 'x', 'low'),
 (22, 'x', 'NA'),
 (23, 'x', 'NA'),
 (24, 'x', 'NA'),
 (25, 'x', 'high'),
 (26, 'x', 'NA')]   
low_list = []
high_list = []
last=0
mark=None
for num,tup in enumerate(a):
    if num == len(a)-1:
        if mark == "high":
            high_list.append([i[0] for i in a[last:]])
        elif mark == "low":
            low_list.append([i[0] for i in a[last:]])
    elif a[num][2] == "high":
        if mark == "low":
            low_list.append([i[0] for i in a[last:num]])
        last = num
        mark = "high"
    elif a[num][2] == "low":
        if mark == "high":
            high_list.append([i[0] for i in a[last:num]])
        last = num
        mark = "low"
low_list
high_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `current_state` to store which state we are in(`low`, `high`, or `NA`), then store the inner list in `sub_list`.

When state changed, the inner list is complete, we start over and append the `sub_list` to the right outer list.

```
vals_list_low = []
vals_list_high = []

sub_list = None
current_state = 'NA'


for x, y, z in lst:
    if z == 'low' or z == 'high':
        state_changed = current_state != z
        current_state = z
        if state_changed:
            sub_list = []
            sub_list.append(x)
            current_list = vals_list_low  if z == 'low' else vals_list_high
            current_list.append(sub_list)
            continue
    if sub_list:
        sub_list.append(x)


print vals_list_low
print vals_list_high
```

The above answer works if two continuous `low` or `high` occurs:

```
a = [(1, 'x', 'NA'),
 (2, 'x', 'low'),
 (3, 'x', 'NA'),
 (4, 'x', 'low'),
 (5, 'x', 'NA'),
 (6, 'x', 'high'),
 (7, 'x', 'NA'),
 (8, 'x', 'NA'),
]
```

gives:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
lst=[(1, 'x', 'NA'),
 (2, 'x', 'low'),
 (3, 'x', 'NA'),
 (4, 'x', 'NA'),
 (5, 'x', 'NA'),
 (6, 'x', 'high'),
 (7, 'x', 'NA'),
 (8, 'x', 'NA'),
 (9, 'x', 'NA'),
 (10, 'x', 'NA'),
 (11, 'x', 'low'),
 (12, 'x', 'NA'),
 (13, 'x', 'NA'),
 (14, 'x', 'NA'),
 (15, 'x', 'high'),
 (16, 'x', 'NA'),
 (17, 'x', 'NA'),
 (18, 'x', 'NA'),
 (19, 'x', 'NA'),
 (20, 'x', 'NA'),
 (21, 'x', 'low'),
 (22, 'x', 'NA'),
 (23, 'x', 'NA'),
 (24, 'x', 'NA'),
 (25, 'x', 'high'),
 (26, 'x', 'NA')]   


def formatlist(inputlist):
    startlist=[]
    returnlist=[]
    for i in inputlist:
        if i == 'border':
            if(startlist):
                returnlist.append(startlist)
            startlist=[]
        else:
            startlist.append(i)
    return returnlist



temp=""
high_lst=[]
low_lst=[]
for i in lst:
    if (i[2]== 'high'):
        temp=""
        high_lst.append('border')
    elif (i[2] == 'low'):
        temp=""
        low_lst.append('border')
    if (i[2]=='high') | (temp == 'high'):
        high_lst.append(i[0])
        temp='high'
    elif (i[2]=='low') | (temp == 'low'):
        low_lst.append(i[0])
        temp='low'

low_lst.append('border')
high_lst.append('border')


print formatlist(low_lst)
print formatlist(high_lst)
```

Comment: i like the additional use of border